# Is something rated as Satisfactory implicitly better than other rated as Sufficient?

Tags: word-meaning, adjectives, comparison

What I mean by this question is:

If I say I'm going to test some products and rate them:

If I rate one as **Satisfactory** and other as **Sufficient**.

Which of the two products is better? Is the **Satisfactory** one implicitly better?

Does the order of the options make sense?

**Options:**

- Very good
- Good
- Satisfactory
- Sufficient
- Bad

Comment: ***Adequate*** is probably more likely than ***sufficient*** in such contexts. But it's entirely arbitrary if you decide to treat either of those as better / worse than, for example, ***satisfactory*** or ***acceptable***. In short, there's no "correct" answer to *How do I "rank" this list of adjectives. It's Primarily Opinion-Based..

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica If the answer is “there’s no unambiguous ranking” it’s an answerable question and not opinion-based?

Comment: @Stephie: I can't really argue with that. But I think there are probably quite a lot of questions asking effectively the same thing *(Please arrange this list of semantically-overlapping words into some kind of "sequence")* - many closed as  POB. So maybe I should have looked for a suitable earlier duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Satisfactory and Sufficient seem to have very similar meanings. I would not be able to distinguish between them.

Your list has the problem that four out of five options suggest "no action needs to be taken".  Using "satisfactory" suggests to some people "everything is okay" but it suggests to others that "Improvements need to be made".

I would suggest (following UK government education guidelines) a four-part ranking:

1. Outstanding
2. Good
3. Requires improvement
4. Inadequate/Poor

The ranking "outstanding" means it is exceptional.  "good" means that there are no major changes needed.  "Requires improvement" means that it is "not good" and so "should be better" and so changes should be made.  Finally "inadequate" means that some things are seriously wrong and urgent changes must be made.  This scale has been shown to be well understood.  If a five-part scale is needed a "very good" could be inserted between outstanding and good (but it doesn't really make the scale easier to use)

Comment: I agree with your overall conclusion and suggestion, but I think something that is _satisfactory_ makes someone _satisfied_, and is thus stronger than something that merely _suffices_. This is really splitting hairs though.

Answer (score 0):

Because they are different semantic categories of words, you can't rank *sufficient* on the same scale as *good*, *satisfactory*, or *bad*.

Consider the following:

> "I see you can't even afford a cup of coffee. Would $1.30 be *sufficient*?"
>   "Yes, thank you. If that's all you can spare, it will still get me what I need for the moment."
>
> "I see you can't even afford a cup of coffee. Would $1 million be *sufficient*?"
>   "Absolutely! Not only will that get me my coffee, but it would be amazing!"

In both cases, *sufficient* is used to indicate the logical ability to accomplish a task—getting a cup of coffee. There is no emotional or normative judgment being placed on the word *sufficient* itself; either it meets the bar of accomplishing the task or it doesn't.

What comes in *addition* to something being sufficient is how you feel about it:

> It is sufficient ***but*** bad.
>   It is sufficient ***and*** satisfactory.
>   It is sufficient ***and*** very good.

---

From Merriam-Webster's definition of [*sufficient*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sufficient):

> **1 a** : enough to meet the needs of a situation or a proposed end
>   // *sufficient* provisions for a month
>   **1 b** : being a sufficient condition

---

As further examples of contrast, and the difference between these semantic categories, consider the following:

> Your generous donations are **very good** and well received, but they are **not sufficient** to keep him fed for a month.
>
> You have kept him prisoner and force-fed him. That is **very bad**, but it was **sufficient** to keep him alive for a month.

Answer (score 0):

These are called **semantic differentiation scales** in marketing and customer satisfaction questionnaires.

[semantic differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_differential)

They work through opposite ends of a scale like: good/bad or satisfactory/unsatisfactory.

This group of words does not conform to a regular good/bad scale semantically as it uses the word sufficient, the opposite of which is insufficient, both of which refer to the idea of "being enough". I would redo the scale like this:

**Very Good

Good

Average

Below Average

Bad**

Most scales when they follow the Likert 5-point method, **use a neutral term in the middle of the scale.**

Like this from that Wikipedia page:

**Strongly disagree [Very poor or bad]

Disagree [Somewhat poor or bad

Neither agree nor disagree [Neither poor or bad]

Agree [good]

Strongly agree [very good]**

Editing the OP's we might get:

**Very good

Good

Not good or bad

Poor

Very poor**

**Very good
Good
Average
Below average 
Very bad**

I would not use this one:
Satisfactory
Acceptable
Average
Unacceptable
Not Satisfactory, because it is difficult to do the five-point scale with it.

I would not use sufficient because its opposite is insufficient and those mean: not enough of something.

> The "rule" for designing a five-point scale is that the end points
>   have to be opposite in meaning and the terms on either side of the
>   middle also should be opposites of each other. **The middle term should signify a
>   neutral attitude from the customer or client or person answering the
>   questionnaire.**

This is the basic premise to keep in mind in designing a satisfaction scale.

The word sufficient (any dictionary will confirm this) means adequate or enough.

I don't believe the OP is testing whether the customer is receiving adequate [x] or enough of [x]. Also, it does not fit the semantic scale. And if the word were to be used, it would have to be paired with insufficient.

"Do you believe you receive proper attention from the company?"

**Insufficient

Not quite sufficient

Average

Almost sufficient

Sufficient**

My example above shows use of the pair sufficient/insufficient and rates the idea of **enough attention or adequate attention** from a company. And I actually am quite dissatisfied with it. satisfied/dissatisfied would have been a better scale to use.

[Likert model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likert_scale)